# Its possible to a static var recieve "require __DIR__.'/paths.php'"?

Tags: php, static, require

workspace: php 5.4, apache 2.4

My code:

```
class Test{

    private static $paths = array();

    self::$paths = require __DIR__.'paths.php';

    //another code
}
```

is it possible to use this?  My objective is to create a variable to recive an array that contain many paths for the app.

Comment: the php DOC says "you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.", but isint clear about how to use or not add after initialize for require...

Comment: Assign properties in the constructor. For static variables, do so from the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that require is more or less an alias for include. Both declarations do load and execute a file. **These functions do not return anything.**

More or less always, you'd like to use these stricter declarations:

- [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)()
- [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)()

I'd propose a pure OO design like so:

```
require( __DIR__  . '/CClassProvider.php' );

class CTestCase {

  protected $_pathArray;

  function __construct() {

      $this->_pathArray = CClassProvider::pathArray();  // from paths.php

   }

}
```

**CClassProvider.php**

```
class CClassProvider {

  static function pathArray() {

    array( '/usr/2', '/usr/3' );

  }

}
```